# How to set an image search text box in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a sample web page to train myself in ASP .Net. The webpage i'm developing is similar to google page. I need the Google Image search page in my web site.

Can anyone please guide me about how
to do that. I am developing the site
 in ASP .Net (C#). I need a search text
 box with a search button. When i click
 the search button i need to fetch the
 image contents from google image
 search and display it in my site. How
 to do that? Please assist me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did u take a look at this http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/

Answer (score 0):

you can find here all google api's

http://code.google.com/more/

and that is google image search api

http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/